# Registry in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, register, registry

I know **how to** `register`, **how to get the value from** `registry` and **how to** `unregister`.

**for register**

```
$this->_coreRegistry->register('customer_save_observer_executed_' . $customer_Data->getId(),true);
```

**for get the value from register**

```
$this->_coreRegistry->registry('customer_save_observer_executed_' . $customer_Data->getId())
```

**for unregister**

```
$this->_coreRegistry->unregister('customer_save_observer_executed_' . $customer_Data->getId());
```

**Now I don't know how long register will hold this information untill if I unregister.**

Expecting valuable suggestions/help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to `Magento\Framework\Registry` you can see a `__destruct` method specified there.

Register basically stores your data inside an array type object using key value pair.

As soon as you stop using that class it will automatically calls the `__destruct` method and that will unregister that variable.

Check [this link](http://www.codechewing.com/library/php-destruct-class-function/) to understand how it works.

And [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2385581/2248131) when destructor wont be called.

### EDIT

Lets suppose you are using the registry class inside a controller. You can access the registry throughout the controller because you have instantiated that registry class in your constructor. But as soon as your execution goes to diff controller you cant access that registry variable. Because that would be destroyed by `__destruct()` automatically. You dont have to unregister it.

Comment: So `__destruct` method won't be call until we call `unregister` method?

Comment: Not really. `__destruct` gets called automatically. `unregister` remove a variable by its key and that has to be called.

Comment: Actually First time user I created as a customer well. After logged into dashboard I am trying to update address from admin panel it's throwing error **Registry key customer_save_observer_executed_9 already exist**. So how can I do in this situation? If I want to save

Comment: Somehow the value is still exists in registry. Probably your execution stopped abruptly or calling exit inside your constructor or something else. Have you tried clearing cache? Is it happening for each customers?